# How to install an add-on from a workspace template init file?

Tags: python, scripting, workspaces

How do I make a workspace-template-file execute a script?

In this case I would like to make the Video_Editing template run a script, which will add some buttons to the header.

That is in playback_functions.py which is located in the same folder as **init**.py

```
bin\Release\2.91\scripts\startup\bl_app_templates_system\Video_Editing\__init__.py
```

This is how to init file is looking with the two lines added:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    import os
    from bpy import context
    screen = context.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'FILE_BROWSER':
            space = area.spaces.active
            params = space.params
            params.use_filter_folder = True

    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath), "playback_functions.py")
    exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_factory_startup_post.append(load_handler)


def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_factory_startup_post.remove(load_handler)
```

playback_functions.py:
https://pasteall.org/Of5O

EDIT:
This works for getting the template installing add-ons, but only when running the script in the Text Editor, and not run as template, so do I do this?

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent
import os

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    #import os
    from bpy import context
    screen = context.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'FILE_BROWSER':
            space = area.spaces.active
            params = space.params
            params.use_filter_folder = True

    path_to_script_dir = bpy.app.binary_path.replace('blender.exe','')+"/2.91/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_system/Script_Editing"
    file_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_script_dir))

    script_list =[]
    for item in file_list:
        if item.endswith('.zip'):
            script_list.append(item)

    for file in file_list:
        path_to_file = os.path.join(path_to_script_dir, item)
        bpy.ops.preferences.addon_install(overwrite=True, target='DEFAULT', filepath=path_to_file, filter_folder=True, filter_python=False, filter_glob="*.py;*.zip")

    enableTheseAddons = ['textension', 'code_editor']

    for string in enableTheseAddons:
        name = enableTheseAddons
        bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module = string)


def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_factory_startup_post.append(load_handler)


def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_factory_startup_post.remove(load_handler)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Updated template folder: [Script_Editing.zip](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/pwKLaqifXSyUjYGXULZZ8NVFJSb.zip) (212.1 KB)
This folder should be unzipped and placed in bin\Release\2.91\scripts\startup\bl_app_templates_system\

Comment: Code (or example) of `playback_functions.py` would add clarity.  eg  If it was an addon or in startup or modules folder or is a registered script in blend file would be automatically imported  as a module and  have  its register method called.

Comment: I've added it as a link above. Thank you.

Comment: Yep.  The classes should be registered in the register method. As is will only do this  in  main thread. Will notice many addons call register from main thread. `if __name__ == "__main__": register()`  This is to emulate what happens when addon is registered, _ie_ it is imported and the register method called. That is what would do here. Import and call register, or install as addon and enable for that workspace.

Comment: I've tried adding this instead: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135045/37272 for installing and enabling as add-ons, but it didn't work for me either. That would be the preferable way to do it. Registering all things from inside the add-ons will be a lot of work in most cases, so I would prefer not to do this.

Comment: @batFINGER I realized that the init file is only called when using Load Factory Settings `bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(app_template="Script_Editing")`, but if you do from the init file, you'll end up in a loop. A catch 22 situation.

Comment: Would consider making an addon that installs the template and associates itself to  the workspace.   A choice is to have one umbrella addon with all your tools  (still favour this)  or one for each ... or a bit of both.  Also adding a folder named scripts with addons, startup etc subfolders to system path is another way to make a group of addons available without having to do much.  Haven't done much on this front, but have an nvim based scripting workspace in mind, am looking for answers re templates with great interest.   On question front have you tried importing and calling the

Comment: register method.

Comment: No need to register. Installing and enabling the add-ons as the script does in the updated first post works, but only when Load Factory Settings is run. It doesn't seem like the init file actually is run when selecting the template at start-up. Which is odd, or even a bug?

Comment: Not that it solves the problem, but add a little more info about templates: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **init**.py file inside the template folder will only be loaded when the user is selecting File - Defaults - Load Factory Settings, and not the the workspace template is selected at start up.

The process is shown in this video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufSyony6eRE